# Problem extracting Pixel Data from bitmap

Tags: c++, image-processing, bitmapimage

I am using native C++ without to build an image processing library from ground up, currently for bitmaps.

For example, I use the following to extract the pixel data from a bitmap after setting the stream's position to the correct location.

```
fread(pixelDataBuffer, sizeof(unsigned char), (height * width), streamIn);
```

Where *height* and *width* are the pixel dimensions of the bitmap image. I thought this would work and makes sense for an image with 8 bits per pixel, but it's still not working (the function returns 0). This happens even though height and width have values of 256 each, and pixelDataBuffer is initialized as below:

```
unsigned char pixelDataBuffer[height * width]; 
// also tried:
unsigned char pixelDataBuffer[65536]; // which is 256*256
```

Thank you!

Adding more code for clarity:

```
bool isTrial = true;
FILE *streamIn;
FILE *outputFile;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    if (isTrial) {
        streamIn = fopen("Images/cameraman.bmp", "rb");
        outputFile = fopen("Images/cameraman_copy.bmp", "wb");
    } else {
        streamIn = fopen("Images/flag.bmp", "rb");
        outputFile = fopen("Images/flag_copy.bmp", "wb");
    }

    unsigned char header[54];
    unsigned char colourTable[1024];

    if (streamIn == nullptr) {
        printf("null pointer");
    } else {

        for (int i = 0; i < 54; i++) {
            header[i] = getc(streamIn);
        }

        unsigned int width = *(int*)&header[18];
        cout << "width: " << width << "\n"; // = 256

        unsigned int height = *(int *)&header[22];
        cout << "height: " << height << "\n"; // = 256

        unsigned short bitDepth = *(short *)&header[28];
        cout << "bitDepth: " << bitDepth << "\n"; // = 8

        unsigned int fileSize = *(int *)&header[2];
        cout << "fileSize: " << fileSize << endl; // 66614

        if (1 < bitDepth && bitDepth <= 8) {
            short count = fread(colourTable, sizeof(unsigned char), 1024, streamIn); 
            if (count == 1024) {
                printf("colourTable read\n"); // colourTable gets read
            } else {
                printf("colourTable NOT read properly");
            }
        } else {
            printf("bitsPerPixel / bitDepth is more than 8");
        }


        { // getting pixelData, at this point I assumed that the stream's position starts where pixel data starts (i.e. after Headers & ColourTable)

            unsigned int pixelDataSize = height * width * (bitDepth/8); // = 65536
            cout << "pixelDataSize: " << pixelDataSize << endl;

            unsigned char pixelDataBuffer[pixelDataSize]; // also tried initializing like unsigned char pixelDataBuffer[height*width]

            short counter = fread(pixelDataBuffer, sizeof(unsigned char), pixelDataSize, streamIn);
            cout << "counter: " << counter << endl; // = 0 THIS IS THE ISSUE. Documentation says "If either size or count is zero, the function returns zero and both the stream state and the content pointed by ptr remain unchanged." But I think I have size and count >0 correctly?

        }


        { // writing our header onto the outputFile
            short count = fwrite(header, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, outputFile);
            if (count == 54) {
                printf("header written\n"); // Header gets written
            } else {
                printf("header not written");
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should read the documentation specific to each image format, however I would assume you should use a 16-bit type, such as uint16_t, also you should probably use uint8_t instead of unsigned char to make sure you have the right size

Comment: unless you're doing this to learn as a learning experience I'd advise you to consider using one of the already available libraries

Comment: definitely for the experience :)

Comment: try reading the specs than http://www.dragonwins.com/domains/GetTechEd/bmp/bmpfileformat.htm
keep in mind that you might meet 1-bit bitmaps which have 1 byte representing 8 pixels

Comment: Yup, I suppose I just have to multiply the number of pixels by the number of bytes per pixel in the case of my function. But my initial problem of the fread (as it is above) returning 0 remains, even though height and width have values of 256 each.

Comment: did you open the stream? need more code for conclusions. Always check if opening succeeds, seeking succeeds, etc.

Comment: OK, I've added the surrounding code and comments to show the run results!!

Comment: You do realize that BMP files use compression, right?

Comment: @Cris, yup but this file doesn't. It's my start file :) Simple 8 bits per pixel bitmap image, no compression

Comment: Also, `bitDepth/8` is 0 if `bitDepth<8`. And `unsigned char pixelDataBuffer[pixelDataSize];` is illegal in C++, it must be a compile-time constant. Use `std::vector` for your buffers.

Comment: @Cris ok, will do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is declaring the result of fread as short.

Try always using auto as much as possible. Using:

```
auto counter = fread(pixelDataBuffer, sizeof(unsigned char), pixelDataSize, streamIn);
```

makes it work. The problem is 65536 cannot be represented in short, in fact it overflows it by just enough that it would seem the result was 0 instead.

If you are using an older version of C++ (before C++11) and you can't use auto use size_t instead (which is the actual return type of fread).

I'd also advise you to learn to break your code into smaller functions and avoid writing huge if blocks, for readability and maintainability in the future.